# Azure Data Factory- Updating or Inserting Values from and to the same source and target table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a job in Azure Data Factory, which takes date value from source table (which is also target table), applies expression with 'DerivedColumn' component on date value and fills the target table column(last_7_days) with the output which is boolean after application of expression. My table is large so truncate table isn't an option since I will be truncating same source. I basically want to either insert or update values to last_7_days column. The other data in the table will remain static and won't change. Since I am new to ADF, any help will be appreciated.
[image: The job looks like this]

Preview of data is also giving me correct value after expression implementation :
[image]

My main aim is to fill up target table with this value after implementation of expression.
My sink looks like this:
[image: sink properties]

I will appreciate any Tips or Suggestion. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: The boolean value in SQL database is '0' or '1',  what the table schema of the table(source or sink)? Can you show us any piece of output data your expect? If the expression output data type is different, there will cause error.

Comment: Column name Type 
date_id int 
date date 
date_formatted_short varchar 
date_formatted_long varchar 
kw varchar 
weekday_name_long varchar 
day_of_month tinyint 
day_of_week tinyint 
day_of_year smallint 
month tinyint 
month_name varchar 
quarter tinyint 
year smallint 
is_working_day bit 
last_7_days bit , i basically want 0 or 1 filled in this column last_7_days

Comment: It sounds like self-update when insert or update the data in the table. I would suggest you create a insert/update trigger on the table in your database. When a new insert or data update happen, the trigger with the function will help you create the `last_7_days`. values for you.

Comment: Hi @Acerace.py, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented in following way and it is working fine. Attaching the JSON as well..

[image]